# Do loanwords have quasi-phonemic vowel reduction?

Tags: loanwords, phonetics

I've started to notice this, and I'm not sure whether my eyes are deceiving me or not, but it seems as if several, but not all loans have a high statistical probability of vowels being reduced/devoiced in contexts where they would be very unlikely to in a native Japanese word, that place being fill-vowels being introduced purely to fit with Japanese phonotactics.

As an example, in the loan “dórama” [accute accent used to indicate accented mora] from English “drama”; the /o/ seems to be almost universally , somewhat, devoiced by many speakers, which would be highly unlikely for an /o/ in between two voiced sounds, in an accented mora in a native word.

I did a spectrographical analysis and it should be clear which of both spectrograms is from “dórama” and which from “dóreka”, by the same speaker:

[[image: dórama vs. dóreka1]

Dark bands at the bottom indicate vowels or vowel-like sounds in spectrograms, for those not in the know of this. It is clear that the dark band in the bottom of the first mora in the first picture takes a far less prominent existence than in the second one, indicating a reduction of vowel-like qualities, as is common for Japanese reduced vowels — it should also be clear that the /m/ in “dórama” has some vowel like qualities, whereas the /k/ in “dóreka” does not.

I have used the speaker Skent from [this list](https://forvo.com/word/%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E/#ja), which I also used for “dóreka”, as he was conveniently in both. One may listen to all the examples of “dórama” there and investigate whether one agrees with me that the “do” mora is uncharacteristically reduced with all speakers, and compare it with [these readings](https://forvo.com/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8C/).

I could find no research that investigated this matter — do any Japanese native speakers have any input on the matter whether they feel that not reducing the “do” in “dórama” would sound unnatural or something else?

Comment: Just for clarity, what is the source materials for the spectral analysis? I assume both words are being pronounced by native Japanese speakers? One thing to note is that the pitch-accent for ドラマ is 1, while どれい is 0. I'm not sure if that would affect the analysis, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I got it from Forvo; I'm not even sure which of the example voices this is, but they all show a this similar pattern. The pitch accent was originally marked in my post but someone edited it out of it for whatever reason. I have restored it. It seemed as if the editor thought the acute accent I used in “doráma” was used to mark the devoiced vowel, not the mora on which the accent lies. Forvo also has multiple readings of “dorágon” of which only one undergoes devoicing; and I rarely hear that word with devoicing, the difference being quite visible under analysis.

Comment: But the accent lies on the first mora, doesn’t it? ドラマ{HLL} (ド↓ラマ) (HLL)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, yes, you seem to be right, looking it up and actually analysing the pitch. I guess my mind put it on the second one because reduced morae can't normally have the accent. That makes it even weirder that it's semi reduced. Now I feel I don't know anything any more.

Comment: I suggest replacing どれい with a word on which the first mora is accented, such as どんぐり (https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%90%E3%82%8A/#ja). At least then you are comparing a loanword and a native word which are both accented in the same place. It might be worth finding a better example than ドラマ as the examples on Forvo are somewhat irregular compared to the NHK Accent version.

Comment: @kandyman yes, I definitely agree; I used dorei as an example because I thought it was an unaccented mora; I will get to that. Though that's not really the greatest example because I am looking for a word that starts with dór-, so I shall use どれ I guess.

Comment: You should compare with どれか, which has the same pattern in terms of mora and pitch.

Comment: @user4092 very well. I updated it. Conveniently, the same speaker was again the one pronouncing “どれか” on *Forvo* and it again showed the same pattern that the accented dó has a far stronger vowel formant than in “ドラマ”, and such a difference seems to be typical of all pronunciations thereof on *Forvo*.

Comment: @Zorf I think you need to make it clear to people who are not familiar with spectographic analysis what you are showing them. What is the upper picture showing and what is the lower picture showing?

Comment: @kandyman Done so.

Comment: I guess I'm pronouncing ドラマ like [dˡɫ̩ʷɐmä] and どれか [do̞ɾ̠e̞kä]. The pronunciation [dˡɫ̩ʷe̞kä] sounds foreign to me, and [do̞ɾ̠ɐmä] is difficult to distinguish from ドーラマ or ドルアマ.

Comment: As a native speaker, I feel no difference in pronouncing 寅さん /tórasan/ ( the main character of a film _Otoko wa Tsurai yo_ )and トラフ /tórafu/  (trough) . feel like /r/ is affecting sound of the preceding /o/, although not sure.